# Should the "evangelicalism" tag be created to match other denominational tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Most denomination tags are in the noun form: [methodism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodism) [protestantism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protestantism) [catholocism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholocism) etc. And then there is [evangelical](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evangelical) which is an adjective. Shouldn't it be changed to [evangelicalism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evangelicalism)? We would probably also need to create a tag synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Many denominations do not have an "-ism" name anyway.  Some examples that come to mind:

- Mennonite
- Brethren
- Church of Christ

If, in the name of consistency, we had a [mennonitism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mennonitism) tag, it would be absurd.  I think the best we can hope for in terms of consistency is to consistently use the term most commonly used to describe a given denomination, regardless of whether the word is a noun (such as the -isms) or an adjective (such as 'Mennonite' or 'Brethren') or a more general descriptive term (such as 'Church of Christ').

Answer (score 2):

I'm in broad agreement with Justin and Caleb that consistency would be good to aim for. Unfortunately it isn't quite attainable if we standardise on "-isms" as "baptism" could mean the Baptist denomination or the act of baptism (or doctrines associated with it). Using "baptism" as a denominational tag would be very confusing.

I also agree with Caleb that an evangelicalism tag  would be seldom used as most questions would (hopefully) be focussed on a particular evangelical denomination or would have a slightly wider scope (protestantism). It could of course be argued that protestantism is equally redundant as a tag for similar reasoning, but that's probably a subject for a separate thread.

Comment: I've been considering the idea that dropping the -isms on all of these might make things easier in the long run. It works well for a few things like Catholicism and Presbyterianism but it becomes really awkward beyond that. Those few example work with generic names like "Catholic" and most denominations have much easier monikers to use.

Comment: Also, I think in spite of the varied usage, "protestant" is a little bit easier to define than "evancelical".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think they should be consistent. (And as moderators if this gets enough votes we can rename it).

However, "evangelicalism" is not a denomination *and* it is a very difficult to categorize word -- in my book it's nearly meaningless. I'm not sure what all should get that tag in the first place. I might argue that we don't have anything yet for which that is an important and definitive enough distinction to even have a tag.